# Can GCC be coerced to generate efficient constructors for memory-aligned objects?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, x86

I'm optimizing a constructor that is called in one of our app's innermost loops. The class in question is about 100 bytes wide, consists of a bunch of `int`s, `float`s, `bool`s, and trivial structs, and should be trivially copyable (it has a nontrivial default constructor, but no destructor or virtual functions). It is constructed often enough that every *nanosecond* of time spent in this ctor works out to around $6,000 of extra server hardware we need to buy.

However, I find that GCC is not emitting very efficient code for this constructor (even with `-O3 -march` etc set). GCC's implementation of the constructor, filling out default values via an initializer list, takes about 34ns to run. If instead of this default constructor I use a hand-written function that writes directly to the object's memory space with a variety of SIMD intrinsics and pointer math, construction takes about 8ns.

Can I get GCC to emit an efficient constructor for such objects when I [`__attribute__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) them to be memory-aligned on SIMD boundaries? Or must I resort to old-school techniques like writing my own memory initializers in assembly?

This object is only ever constructed as a local on the stack, so any new/malloc overhead doesn't apply.

**Context:**

This class is used by constructing it on the stack as a local variable, selectively writing a few fields with non-default values, and then passing it (by reference) to a function, which passes its reference to another and so on.

```
struct Trivial {
  float x,y,z;
  Trivial () : x(0), y(0), z(0) {};
};

struct Frobozz
{
   int na,nb,nc,nd;
   bool ba,bb,bc;
   char ca,cb,cc;
   float fa,fb;
   Trivial va, vb; // in the real class there's several different kinds of these
   // and so on
   Frobozz() : na(0), nb(1), nc(-1), nd(0),
               ba(false), bb(true), bc(false),
               ca('a'), cb('b'), cc('c'),
               fa(-1), fb(1.0) // etc
    {}
} __attribute__(( aligned(16) ));

// a pointer to a func that takes the struct by reference
typedef int (*FrobozzSink_t)( Frobozz& );

// example of how a function might construct one of the param objects and send it
// to a sink. Imagine this is one of thousands of event sources:
int OversimplifiedExample( int a, float b )
{
   Frobozz params; 
   params.na = a; params.fb = b; // other fields use their default values
   FrobozzSink_t funcptr = AssumeAConstantTimeOperationHere();
   return (*funcptr)(params);
}
```

The optimal constructor here would work by copying from a static "template" instance into the freshly constructed instance, ideally using SIMD operators to work 16 bytes at a time. Instead GCC does exactly the wrong thing for OversimplifiedExample() — a series of immediate mov ops to fill out the struct byte-by-byte.

```
// from objdump -dS
int OversimplifiedExample( int a, float b )
{
     a42:55                   push   %ebp
     a43:89 e5                mov    %esp,%ebp
     a45:53                   push   %ebx
     a46:e8 00 00 00 00       call   a4b <_Z21OversimplifiedExampleif+0xb>
     a4b:5b                   pop    %ebx
     a4c:81 c3 03 00 00 00    add    $0x3,%ebx
     a52:83 ec 54             sub    $0x54,%esp
     // calling the 'Trivial()' constructors which move zero, word by word...
     a55:89 45 e0             mov    %eax,-0x20(%ebp)
     a58:89 45 e4             mov    %eax,-0x1c(%ebp)
     a5b:89 45 e8             mov    %eax,-0x18(%ebp)
     a5e:89 45 ec             mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
     a61:89 45 f0             mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
     a64:89 45 f4             mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
     // filling out na/nb/nc/nd..
     a67:c7 45 c4 01 00 00 00 movl   $0x1,-0x3c(%ebp)
     a71:c7 45 c8 ff ff ff ff movl   $0xffffffff,-0x38(%ebp)
     a78:89 45 c0             mov    %eax,-0x40(%ebp)
     a7b:c7 45 cc 00 00 00 00 movl   $0x0,-0x34(%ebp)
     a82:8b 45 0c             mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
     // doing the bools and chars by moving one immediate byte at a time!
     a85:c6 45 d0 00          movb   $0x0,-0x30(%ebp)
     a89:c6 45 d1 01          movb   $0x1,-0x2f(%ebp)
     a8d:c6 45 d2 00          movb   $0x0,-0x2e(%ebp)
     a91:c6 45 d3 61          movb   $0x61,-0x2d(%ebp)
     a95:c6 45 d4 62          movb   $0x62,-0x2c(%ebp)
     a99:c6 45 d5 63          movb   $0x63,-0x2b(%ebp)
     // now the floats...
     a9d:c7 45 d8 00 00 80 bf movl   $0xbf800000,-0x28(%ebp)
     aa4:89 45 dc             mov    %eax,-0x24(%ebp)
     // FrobozzSink_t funcptr = GetFrobozz();
     aa7:e8 fc ff ff ff       call   aa8 <_Z21OversimplifiedExampleif+0x68>
     // return (*funcptr)(params);
     aac:8d 55 c0             lea    -0x40(%ebp),%edx
     aaf:89 14 24             mov    %edx,(%esp)
     ab2:ff d0                call   *%eax
     ab4:83 c4 54             add    $0x54,%esp
     ab7:5b                   pop    %ebx
     ab8:c9                   leave 
     ab9:c3                   ret   
}
```

I tried to encourage GCC to construct a single 'default template' of this object, and then bulk-copy it in the default constructor, by doing a bit of trickery with a hidden 'dummy' constructor that made the base exemplar and then having the default just copy it:

```
struct Frobozz
{
     int na,nb,nc,nd;
     bool ba,bb,bc;
     char ca,cb,cc;
     float fa,fb;
     Trivial va, vb;
     inline Frobozz();
private:
     // and so on
     inline Frobozz( int dummy ) : na(0), /* etc etc */     {}
} __attribute__( ( aligned( 16 ) ) );

Frobozz::Frobozz( )
{
     const static Frobozz DefaultExemplar( 69105 );
     // analogous to copy-on-write idiom
     *this = DefaultExemplar;
     // or:
     // memcpy( this, &DefaultExemplar, sizeof(Frobozz) );
}
```

But this generated even *slower* code than the basic default with initializer list, due to some redundant stack copying.

Finally I resorted to writing an inlined free function to do the `*this = DefaultExemplar` step, using compiler intrinsics and assumptions about memory alignment to issue [pipelined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_pipelining) [MOVDQA](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc183.htm) SSE2 opcodes that copy the struct efficiently. This got me the performance I need, but it's icky. I thought my days of writing initializers in assembly were behind me, and I'd really rather just have GCC's optimizer emit the right code in the first place.

**Is there some way I can get GCC to generate optimal code for my constructor, some compiler setting or additional `__attribute__` I've missed?**

This is GCC 4.4 running on Ubuntu. Compiler flags include `-m32 -march=core2 -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC` (among others). Portability is *not* a consideration, and I'm thoroughly willing to sacrifice standards-compliance for performance here.

Timings were performed by directly reading the time stamp counter with `rdtsc`, *eg* measuring a loop of ***N*** OversimplifiedExample() calls between samples with due attention to timer resolution and cache and statistical significance and so on.

I've also optimized this by reducing the number of call sites as much as possible, of course, but I'd still like to know how to generally get better ctors out of GCC.

Comment: Did you try a more recent GCC, like 4.6.2 (or the latest snapshot of the soon to be released 4.7) ?

Comment: Can you omit the definition of the constructor and write it entirely by hand in asm? Risky and difficult to maintain, but for 34*$6000 it'd pay for itself I suspect

Comment: Have you also tried adding some of the various `-msse` flags? I think they are needed for sse in certain cases. Also I suggest you simply get a recent gcc and browse its manpage, thinking about if every option can improve your situation and then try it out.

Comment: Does the function `OversimplifiedExample` need to be re-entrant and/or thread-safe? And can you tell where I'm headed with this? ;-)

Comment: @PlasmaHH -march=core2 implies -msse and -msse2. (Also sse3 for what it's worth.)

Comment: Maybe it would be better to tackle the problem from another angle? Why are you even creating so many of these structs? Maybe you could improve on that point with pools or somesuch stuff.

Comment: @Steve Ha, I had the same thought! It does need to be reentrant, unfortunately; each FrobozzSink may dispatch additional.. um... Frobozz-es.

Comment: Or swap the `float x,y,z` etc. for `__m128 vec`?

Comment: @Xeo The first angle of attack was to reduce the number of things I need to construct, of course! But even with the redundant work gone, there's still hundreds of thousands of calls per second. Pooling allocators wouldn't help here since the objects are only ever on the stack anyway.

Comment: @Crashworks: curses. If the recursion is reasonably limited, you might still be able to do something with a `static` array of Frobozzes, plus a `static` counter of how deep you currently are and hence which index to use.

Comment: @awoodland The vector type is only an example -- there's actually a bunch of different (trivial) substructures packed in there. But you're right in that what I want to get GCC to do is use the _m128 type to copy this, without my having to actually union it with an _m128 array and do the work by hand.

Comment: @Crash: I'm not talking about pooling allocators, but object pools. Instead of deconstructing and reconstructing those Frobozzes every time, you just reinitialize the parts you actually need. Maybe that could help.

Comment: @Steve Well, I've already fixed the problem with a few hours' work by just writing the assembly. But now I'm curious to see if I'm just using GCC incorrectly, if there's some way to get it to emit better code.

Comment: @Xeo That's what I'm trying to do with the "default template" pattern above: I construct just one static instance with all the default fields, then for each new instance, copy the static onto the stack and fill just the necessary members. It's super fast if I do it manually with intrinsics, but for some reason GCC's default copy constructor is relatively slow.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I would do it. Don't declare any constructor; instead, declare a fixed Frobozz that contains default values:

```
const Frobozz DefaultFrobozz =
  {
  0, 1, -1, 0,        // int na,nb,nc,nd;
  false, true, false, // bool ba,bb,bc;
  'a', 'b', 'c',      // char ca,cb,cc;
  -1, 1.0             // float fa,fb;
  } ;
```

Then in `OversimplifiedExample`:

```
Frobozz params (DefaultFrobozz) ;
```

With `gcc -O3` (version 4.5.2), the initialisation of `params` reduces to:

```
leal    -72(%ebp), %edi
movl    $_DefaultFrobozz, %esi
movl    $16, %ecx
rep movsl
```

which is about as good as it gets in a 32-bit environment.

**Warning:** I tried this with the 64-bit g++ version 4.7.0 20110827 (experimental), and it generated an explicit sequence of 64-bit copies instead of a block move. The processor doesn't allow `rep movsq`, but I would expect `rep movsl` to be faster than a sequence of 64-bit loads and stores. Perhaps not. (But the `-Os` switch -- optimise for space -- does use a `rep movsl` instruction.) Anyway, try this and let us know what happens.

**Edited to add:** I was wrong about the processor not allowing `rep movsq`. Intel's documentation says "The MOVS, MOVSB, MOVSW, and MOVSD instructions can be preceded by the REP prefix", but it seems that this is just a documentation glitch. In any case, if I make `Frobozz` big enough, then the 64-bit compiler generates `rep movsq` instructions; so it probably knows what it's doing.

Comment: "Don't declare any constructor" - you could declare-private-without-defining (or delete) the no-arg constructor, to ensure that nobody accidentally ends up with an uninitialized object. They either copy the default, or they use an initializer list, but they can't just write `Frobozz params;`. Personally I'd feel happier about existing code if the default constructor disappeared entirely, rather than changing its behavior to do something that's wrong ;-)

Comment: "but I would expect rep movsd to be faster than a sequence of 64-bit loads and stores" there is threshold where the `REP MOVS` instructions will generally be slower. also, `REP MOVS` requires 3 explicit registers `ECX`, `ESI` and `EDI`, which might lead to excessive registers shuffling/spilling as apposed to block copies.