# Exceptions, move semantics and optimizations: at compiler's mercy (MSVC2010)?

Tags: c++, exception, optimization, compiler-construction, move-semantics

While doing some upgrades to my old exception classes hierarchy to utilize some of C++11 features, I did some speed tests and came across results that are somewhat frustrating. All of this was done with x64bit MSVC++2010 compiler, maximum speed optimization /O2.

Two very simple `struct`'s, both bitwise copy semantics. One without move assignment operator (why would you need one?), another  - with. Two simple inlined function returning by value newly created instances of these `struct`s, which get assigned to local variable. Also, notice `try/catch` block around. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

struct TFoo
{
  unsigned long long int m0;
  unsigned long long int m1;

  TFoo( unsigned long long int f ) : m0( f ), m1( f / 2 ) {}
};

struct TBar
{
  unsigned long long int m0;
  unsigned long long int m1;

  TBar( unsigned long long int f ) : m0( f ), m1( f / 2 ) {}
  TBar & operator=( TBar && f )
  {
   m0 = f.m0;
   m1 = f.m1;
   f.m0 = f.m1 = 0;

   return ( *this );
  }
};

TFoo MakeFoo( unsigned long long int f )
{
 return ( TFoo( f ) );
}

TBar MakeBar( unsigned long long int f )
{
 return ( TBar( f ) );
}

int main( void )
{
 try
 {
  unsigned long long int lMin = 0;
  unsigned long long int lMax = 20000000;
  LARGE_INTEGER lStart = { 0 };
  LARGE_INTEGER lEnd = { 0 };
  TFoo lFoo( 0 );
  TBar lBar( 0 );

  ::QueryPerformanceCounter( &lStart );
  for( auto i = lMin; i < lMax; i++ )
  {
   lFoo = MakeFoo( i );
  }
  ::QueryPerformanceCounter( &lEnd );
  std::cout << "lFoo = ( " << lFoo.m0 << " , " << lFoo.m1 << " )\t\tMakeFoo count : " << lEnd.QuadPart - lStart.QuadPart << std::endl;

  ::QueryPerformanceCounter( &lStart );
  for( auto i = lMin; i < lMax; i++ )
  {
   lBar = MakeBar( i );
  }
  ::QueryPerformanceCounter( &lEnd );
  std::cout << "lBar = ( " << lBar.m0 << " , " << lBar.m1 << " )\t\tMakeBar count : " << lEnd.QuadPart - lStart.QuadPart << std::endl;
 }
 catch( ... ){}

 return ( 0 );
}
```

Program output:

```
lFoo = ( 19999999 , 9999999 )       MakeFoo count : 428652
lBar = ( 19999999 , 9999999 )       MakeBar count : 74518
```

Assembler for both loops (showing surrounding counter calls ) :

```
//- MakeFoo loop START --------------------------------
00000001`3f4388aa 488d4810        lea     rcx,[rax+10h]
00000001`3f4388ae ff1594db0400    call    qword ptr [Prototype_Console!_imp_QueryPerformanceCounter (00000001`3f486448)]

00000001`3f4388b4 448bdf          mov     r11d,edi
00000001`3f4388b7 48897c2428      mov     qword ptr [rsp+28h],rdi
00000001`3f4388bc 0f1f4000        nop     dword ptr [rax]
00000001`3f4388c0 4981fb002d3101  cmp     r11,1312D00h
00000001`3f4388c7 732a            jae     Prototype_Console!main+0x83 (00000001`3f4388f3)
00000001`3f4388c9 4c895c2450      mov     qword ptr [rsp+50h],r11
00000001`3f4388ce 498bc3          mov     rax,r11
00000001`3f4388d1 48d1e8          shr     rax,1
00000001`3f4388d4 4889442458      mov     qword ptr [rsp+58h],rax       // these 3 lines
00000001`3f4388d9 0f28442450      movaps  xmm0,xmmword ptr [rsp+50h]    // are of interest 
00000001`3f4388de 660f7f442430    movdqa  xmmword ptr [rsp+30h],xmm0    // see MakeBar
00000001`3f4388e4 49ffc3          inc     r11
00000001`3f4388e7 4c895c2428      mov     qword ptr [rsp+28h],r11        
00000001`3f4388ec 4c8b6c2438      mov     r13,qword ptr [rsp+38h]       // this one too
00000001`3f4388f1 ebcd            jmp     Prototype_Console!main+0x50 (00000001`3f4388c0)

00000001`3f4388f3 488d8c24c0000000 lea     rcx,[rsp+0C0h]
00000001`3f4388fb ff1547db0400    call    qword ptr [Prototype_Console!_imp_QueryPerformanceCounter (00000001`3f486448)]
//- MakeFoo loop END --------------------------------

//- MakeBar loop START --------------------------------
00000001`3f4389d1 488d8c24c8000000 lea     rcx,[rsp+0C8h]
00000001`3f4389d9 ff1569da0400    call    qword ptr [Prototype_Console!_imp_QueryPerformanceCounter (00000001`3f486448)]

00000001`3f4389df 4c8bdf          mov     r11,rdi
00000001`3f4389e2 48897c2440      mov     qword ptr [rsp+40h],rdi
00000001`3f4389e7 4981fb002d3101  cmp     r11,1312D00h
00000001`3f4389ee 7322            jae     Prototype_Console!main+0x1a2 (00000001`3f438a12)
00000001`3f4389f0 4c895c2478      mov     qword ptr [rsp+78h],r11
00000001`3f4389f5 498bf3          mov     rsi,r11
00000001`3f4389f8 48d1ee          shr     rsi,1
00000001`3f4389fb 4d8be3          mov     r12,r11                     // these 3 lines
00000001`3f4389fe 4c895c2468      mov     qword ptr [rsp+68h],r11     // are of interest
00000001`3f438a03 48897c2478      mov     qword ptr [rsp+78h],rdi     // see MakeFoo
00000001`3f438a08 49ffc3          inc     r11
00000001`3f438a0b 4c895c2440      mov     qword ptr [rsp+40h],r11
00000001`3f438a10 ebd5            jmp     Prototype_Console!main+0x177 (00000001`3f4389e7)

00000001`3f438a12 488d8c24c0000000 lea     rcx,[rsp+0C0h]
00000001`3f438a1a ff1528da0400    call    qword ptr [Prototype_Console!_imp_QueryPerformanceCounter (00000001`3f486448)]
//- MakeBar loop END --------------------------------
```

Both times are the same if I remove `try/catch` block. But in presence of it, compiler clearly optimizes code better for `struct` with redundant move operator=. Also, `MakeFoo` time does dependent on the size of `TFoo` and its layout, but in, general, time is several worse than for `MakeBar` for which time does not depend on small size changes.

**Questions**:

1. Is it compiler specific feature ofy MSVC++2010 (could someone check for GCC?)?
2. Is it because compiler has to preserve temporary until the call finishes, it cannot "rip it apart" in case of `MakeFoo`, and in case of `MakeBar` it knows that we allow it to use move semantics and it "rips it apart", generating faster code?
3. Can I expect same behavior for similar things without `try\catch` block, but in more complicated scenarios?

Comment: Just a note, Visual Studio is retarded with move constructors

Comment: @SethCarnegie You should see how awful GCC is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894695/can-gcc-be-coerced-to-generate-efficient-constructors-for-memory-aligned-objects

Answer (score 2):

Your test is flawed.  When compiled with `/O2 /EHsc`, it runs to completion in a fraction of a second and there is high variability in the results of the test.

I retried the same test, but ran it for 100x as many iterations, with the following results (the results were similar across several runs of the test):

```
lFoo = ( 1999999999 , 999999999 )               MakeFoo count : 16584927
lBar = ( 1999999999 , 999999999 )               MakeBar count : 16613002
```

Your test does not show any difference between the performance of assignment of the two types.

Comment: I highly suspect, you do not have `try\catch` block around the code. Because times are same and both functions run really fast in the absence of `try\catch`. The behavior manifests itself only in presence of `try\catch`... Also, what's your compiler bitness and could you show me your assembler?.. And, sorry, what do you mean by "Your test is flawed"? Did I fabricate assembler instructions? My compiler version is `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64`

Comment: I copied the exact code from your question.  I made no modifications to it other than to change the number of iterations.  Your test is flawed because it runs for too few iterations, causing high variability in the test results.  You should upgrade to the SP1 compiler (you are using the RTM compiler from early 2010; the SP1 compiler is version 10.00.40219.01).  My tests are with the SP1 compiler; I get similar results for both tests compiling for both x86 and x64.  If you increase the number of iterations by 100x, do you still see the difference?

Comment: Also, I use `/EHa`, but using `/EHsc` as you suggest does not change a thing. At least, not with the compiler I have... What's your counter frequency? Mine is `2591279`. So this test does take some time to run. I'll increase 100x times, doubt it'll change anything.

Comment: Well, I run it for 100x longer, counts are the same, except 100 times larger: `42808193` and `7443621`... I think, your suggestion about SP1 compiler might be a valid one, it could be the compiler version. Is that what you are talking about: [MS VC++ 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4422)?

Comment: I have updated compiler to `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for x64`. The results have not changed. I'm running `Windows SDK 7.1` compilers (SP1 now) from command line with `nmake`. Any other information would be useful? And can you, please, show your assembler?.. My compilation flags for `cl.exe` are : `/nologo /c /EHa /W4 /WL /Zi /FAcs /O2`.

Comment: [Sorry for the delay; I'm not ignoring your question; I'll get back to you tomorrow when I'm in the office and can recompile your source.]

Comment: No problem, James. Thanks for going into all the trouble and trying to help.